# Implementing single sign on between multiple Firebase instances

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm trying to create a single sign on between multiple Firebase instances. So let's say I have a project called UserBase, and then I have another projects called Sales. Both projects use the same users, so I will configure Firebase Authentication on the UserBase project and I want to sign in on the other one with the same users.

What I thought was something like this:

I create a web page login.example.com, that is connected to the UserBase project, and it accepts a username and password, and another page for sales that will redirect to this page.

The user go to Sales and clicks on "Sign in", it will open a popup window for login.example.com with a callback address. When successfully signed in, I'll get the token with user.getIdToken and send it to a Cloud Function (UserBase) that will validate the token and pass it to another Cloud Function (Sales) using the callback address, that will return a token for Sales, and this token will be returned to the Sales page, and then I will use signInWithCustomToken to sign in with a valid Sales Token.

Something like this:

TokenU is the JWT for UserBase, tokenS is the JWT for Sales

```
|Sales page| -callback-> |Login page| -tokenU-> |UserBase Cloud Function| -token?-> |Sales Cloud Function|
|          | <--tokenS-- |          | <-tokenS- |                       | <-tokenS- |                    |
```

Everything works, but right now I'm sending just the uid unencripted and unsigned from the UserBase Cloud Function to the Sales Cloud Function, which is obviously not ideal, or else anyone could sign in with just the uid.

This is just a simplified example, we will have dozens of connected but independent projects, only sharing the user, and each project has its own data (Firestore and Storage) so to protect that I believe I need the user to exist in each one, which can be accomplished by creating tokens with the same uid on all projects. Also, ideally the user should only type the password once for all projects.

So I have two questions:

1. How do I securely send the user from the UserBase Cloud Function to the Sales Cloud Function without sharing the private key?
2. Assuming question 1 is resolved, is this a valid and secure scenario?

Comment: @AndréKool This is just a simplified example, we will have dozens of connected but independent projects, only sharing the user, and each project has its own data (Firestore and Storage) so to protect that I need the user to exist in each one. Also, ideally the user should only sign in once for all of the projects. Do you see a way to solve those questions with multiple projects?

Comment: Did you find a Solution?